# Does a Page Mode SRAM similar to Page Mode DRAM exist?

Tags: memory, dram

Page Mode DRAM is essentially doing multiple column accesses per a single row access. This seems pretty logical to me, but I couldn't find anything similar written about SRAM. Does standard SRAM already do this and is there a name for it? If SRAM only does a single column access per a row access, why is that?

Comment: What kind of SRAM are you looking the answer for? SRAM comes in all different varieties.